# How to set custom prompt when opening a new xterm?

Tags: linux, prompt, csh, tcsh, xterm

I want to open a new xterm with a custom prompt string.
Since prompt is set using the `prompt` variable, I thought I could just run:

`xterm -e "set prompt = $prompt_string_of_my_choosing" #The organization I work for uses tcsh`

The problem is, I want the xterm to stay interactive.
I tried `tcsh -c` as a command for `-e`, I tried sourcing another script that would set the prompt to the way I want it . The results I'm getting are either an interactive shell with the default prompt, or an xterm that just closes (or stays open with `-hold` but not interactive).

I was however able to bypass the problem by adding the following to `~/.cshrc`:

`if ($?calling_prompt) then
    set prompt = "$calling_prompt"
endif`

And of course I preset the `$calling_prompt` variable in advance.
This works, but requires me to edit `~/.cshrc`, so it's not a global solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, I was going to suggest doing the `calling_prompt` hack, until I saw you'd already tried and rejected that option.  It just doesn't seem tcsh has an option for executing a script (or inline code) before entering interactive mode.  And it doesn't appear to respect an exported prompt variable nor allow you to pick an alternate configuration file.  So it seems your best option is still editing .cshrc/.tcshrc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set variable being a flag for your new term and than use this approach:

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=2582

This way, you can alway set whatever you like in prompt - e.g. based on type of term you have started.